# This is inconceivable. Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Grandpa likes a Whale but not a Hippo
>
> Grandpa likes Hulk but not Frankenstein
>
> Grandpa likes a Foot but not Eighteen inches

Why?

**Hint**

> Things he dislikes are linked together by an incredible single long word

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Grandpa has

> Hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia

His three dislikes

> compose the three parts of the phobia.

Hippo

> Hippopoto --> Hippo

Frankenstein

> monstro --> Monster (Frankenstein)

Eighteen Inches

> sesquipedalio --> Latin literally meaning [one and a half feet long](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesquipedalian)

As for his likes:

> They are all short words

And as for the hint:

> hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia is an incredibly long word.

Comment: If this is the answer, seems more appropriate for the description to use "hippopotamus" as opposed to the shortened "hippo".

Comment: Your answer is in my bio! :)

Comment: If this is correct it also would be more appropriate to use pick any other famous monster reference that refers to the monster rather than the scientist.

Answer (score 3):

One rule that fits all the information we have so far is that

> Grandpa likes a thing if, and only if, its name doesn't contain the letter I.

In this case

> the things he dislikes are linked together by the word "I". Is that word "incredible" and "inconceivable"? Well, for a slightly far-fetched affirmative answer, consider the phrase "I couldn't believe my 'I's" ... :-).

For what it's worth, my guess is that this is not the intended answer. But I think we need rather more information in order to nail down a single right answer. I don't think anything's *wrong* with the one above, and I bet there are several other answers of approximately equal plausibility.

Comment: Right @Gareth McCaughan. I modified the hint.

Answer (score 2):

> Grandpa dislikes words with multiple syllables

Comment: Good observation. Did not realize this when I designed it.